# Reorder columns according to rankings specified in another data frame

Tags: r

I  have two data frames. The first data frame has 100 columns. I want to re-order its 3rd through 100th column according to rankings specified in the second data frame. For example, if the first data frame is

```
     Product   Attribute  flowers  stones  house   pool
     A         large       100      200     300    500
     B         medium      200      500     400    600
     C         small       300      400     300    200
```

And the second data set is

```
    Name        Rank
    flowers     3
    stones      4
    house       1
    pool        2
```

Then after the desired step, the new dataset should look like

```
    Product   Attribute   house   pool   flowers  stones
    A         large       300     500    100      200
    B         medium      400     600    200      500
    C         small       300     200    300      400
```

According to the answer below, I tried this:

```
      Product=c("A","B","C")
      flowers=c(100,200,300)
      stones=c(200,500,400)
      house=c(300,400,500)
      pool=c(500,600,200)
      dat1=data.frame(Product,flowers,stones,house,pool)

     Name=c("flowers","stones","house","pool")
     Rank=c(3,4,1,2)
     dat2=data.frame(Name,Rank)

     indx <- c(names(dat1)[1:1],with(dat2, Name[Rank]))
     dat1[,indx]
```

But the last line doesn't run has has this error message:

```
      Error in `[.data.frame`(dat1, , indx) : undefined columns selected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dat1` and `dat2` are the `first` and `second` datasets

```
indx <- c(names(dat1)[1],as.character(with(dat2, Name[Rank])))
dat1[,indx]
```

#### Explanation

- `dat2$Rank` gives a numeric index  `[1] 3 4 1 2`
- When we use `dat2$Name[dat2$Rank]` or `with(dat2, Name[Rank])` it rearranges the `Name` column according to the order specified in the `Rank` column. ie.

  ```
   [1] house   pool    flowers stones
   Levels: flowers house pool stones
  ```
- As this is a factor (because `Name` in your `dat2` is factor), you can use`as.character` to convert this to `character class
- `names(dat1)[1]` is `Product`.  Concatenate this to the previous result gives you the names of columns in `dat1` in the specified order.  Use this as name index to get the columns from `dat1`

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work... the first line can run OK. the second has such error message "Error in `[.data.frame`(dat1, , indx) : undefined columns selected". Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Also, even the output "indx" of the first line does not make sense to me either. Can you please advise?

Comment: @user3698033  Thank you for providing a reproducible example.  When I read the data, I used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` so that the character columns remained as `character` class.  In your new dataset `dat2`, column `Name` is a factor.  Now your new `dat1` doesn't have the `Attribute` column.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
dat1[c(names(dat1)[1], as.character(dat2[order(dat2$Rank),][, "Name"]))]

#   Product house pool flowers stones
# 1       A   300  500     100    200
# 2       B   400  600     200    500
# 3       C   500  200     300    400
```

Comment: it works. But how to retain the first column ("Product") in dat1?

Comment: @user3698033, Please unaccept this. akrun's answer is correct. See my edit on his answer